# ODBC output is there an easier way - Using C# ASP.NET MVC 4/5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odbc

My company use's ODBC for data collection and the goal is to pull multiple sources of data into one place. 
Currently (as shown below) I have a connection setup in the top of my controller that connects to the company provided ODBC connection. I pass the column names to an array list which is passed to a ViewBag. I do the same for the collection Data. 
This ends up giving me a "flat array" with no index key's or anything to reference.

**myList**

array = Column Name[0], Column Name[1], Column Name[2]

**Data**

array = Row[0], Row[1], Row[2], Row[0], Row[1], Row[2], Row[0], Row[1], Row[2]

In order to output the data in a form that actually makes sense to my end user I do some hacking within my View to output data. I take a count of the data array in the above example it's 9. I count my cells to get my header row in the above example it's 3. I create a for loop and within it I iterate through to count the difference in my headers to the row's so I can get the ending row of data and reset the tr. My ending output is below for reference.

**[My Question]**

Is there a simpler way to use the `.Read()` command? And how do I add my data to a multi-dimensional array and output the content of each row's individual value?

***Output Index.html***

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Column Name[0]</th>
<th>Column Name[1]</th>
<th>Column Name[2]</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Row[0]</td><td>Row[1]</td><td>Row[2]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row[0]</td><td>Row[1]</td><td>Row[2]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row[0]</td><td>Row[1]</td><td>Row[2]</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

***Controller - Project.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
public class ODBC: Controller
{
    OdbcConnection DBConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Server;UID=USER;PWD=PASS;DATABASE=DATA-MARKET");

  public ActionResult Index()
    {

DBConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand DbCommand = DBConnection.CreateCommand();
        DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT \"ID\", \"Request ID\", \"Service ID\", \"Summary\" FROM    dbo.\"Records\" WHERE (\"Status Rejected User\" IS NULL)"; 
        OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

        int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();


        for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(DbReader.GetName(i));
        }


        ViewBag.Count = myList;

        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();



        while (DbReader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
            {
                data.Add(DbReader.GetValue(i));
            }
        }



        ViewBag.fCount = fCount;
        DbReader.Close();
        DbCommand.Dispose();
        DBConnection.Close();
        ViewBag.data = data;
        return View();
    }
```

***View - Index.CSHTML***

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Controllers.ODBCController>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var cell_count = @ViewBag.Count.Count;
}

<h2>Index -</h2>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<tr>

 @foreach( var ls in @ViewBag.Count){

 <th>@ls</th>
 }
</tr>
<tbody>  

     @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.data.Count; i++)
{
    var cells = cell_count;
    var item = ViewBag.data[i];

    if ((i % cells) == 0)
    {
        @:<tr>
    }

    <td>
        @item
    </td>

    if (i == (ViewBag.data.Count - 1))
    {
        while ((i % cells) != 0)
        {
            @:<td></td>
            i++;
        }
    }

    if ((i % cells) == (cells - 1)) // aka: last row cell
    {
        @:</tr>
    }
}

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: you can bypass ODBC by creating and or setting up multiple connection strings in the web.config. we currently use Oracle DB as well as Sql Server and have figured out a simple way to do this eliminating the need for ODBC.. look at this link for how to configure your connection strings based on the type of Database provider you are using [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Does it matter if the web.config holds my connection string or if the string is declared in the controller? Are you suggesting that I can use another provider and access the data from the ODBC View I connect too? In Order to create list's and proper arrays for iterating through in my index.cshtml?

Comment: you can hold as many connection strings in a web.config as well as to multiple and or different databases in the config file under the <ConnectionStrings> node.. you do not need ODBC at all if you understand how to access and or connect to the database are you familiar with how to connect to database using web.config as well as how to configure connection strings..?

Comment: I have multiple connection strings to the SQL server within my web.config. This one controller is pulling data from a database (ODBC SQL) that I only have access to the views not the tables. The Views are setup accordingly and contain the FK's and Constraints. I can't alter their database.  When I opt-out of ODBC and use SQL as the provider I end up with the ability to see my views but I can not run queries against the views, Access is always denied. The only way I have been able to access the data is via ODBC commands.

Comment: Can you show how the config is setup.. I think that you may be missing my point.. you findout what the user id is and user password is for the odbc connection.. and just put it in the connection string of the config file you are making this harder than it needs to be.. I do this on a daily basis for multiple database connections show me what your config looks like

Comment: I can access the data just fine with ODBC, that's not the problem. The problem is that the data does not present it's self as a multi-dimensional array. Instead I am given an array of data that simply looks like this "header, header, header,data,data,data,data,data,data"  I am left to create logic to convert that into something user's can understand.

Comment: What kind of database is that.? why does the select command look so odd..

Comment: Why don't you make strongly typed classes and map the data coming out of the reader into an array of objects?  I am unclear on why you are taking this approach.

Comment: We use 8 ticketing systems. Each system is different, but they all have a view that allows me to query with like-commands. The problem is each ticketing system has anywhere between 100 - 400 column names and I have no data dictionaries to reference. Creating a strongly typed class would mean I would need to know each fields Type and Name. I have Names, but I do not have Types. It made more sense to query (the above example being condensed for breviaries sake.) and use C# in the view to control the output. If there is an easier way to do it..Im down.

Comment: Use or create a type generator.  Run each query and then interrogate the field name and type and generate a class out of it.  You can do this a variety of ways, including T4 templates.

Comment: Creating a Generator to define my class seems like a lot of work for something I feel should be out-of-box actions. If that's the only way, I will do it. You've got to admit, my hack certainly is..creative? haa How would I map reader into an array? The way I currently am doing it is within my loop I simply do an .add and .getname. Is there a way I can define a row explicitly with .add while using my reader?